# What's a word for someone who recruits new members and reminds people to take part in events?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In particular our student group/club in college has a new officer position that performs these duties, but we don't have a good name for it yet. "Recruiter" captures the first part, but it doesn't seem to capture the second part.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in college, the jobs you're describing were performed by people with titles like

- Vice President for Membership
- Social Coordinator
- Personnel Officer

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to a PR Officer ( Public Relation )

**Public Relation:**

a. the practice of creating, promoting, or maintaining goodwill and a favourable image among the public towards an institution, public body, etc
b. the methods and techniques employed
[Public relation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Public+relation)

Answer (score 0):

Take a page from the political system.

**Chief Whip**

The *chief whip* is a person who ensure other party members attends and cast their votes on issues. Although it does not specifically cover the 'recruiting part' I think it perfectly cover your '*remind people to take part*' and can provide a bit of ..... fun to the titles of such a club/organization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Whip